# In Azure AD B2C, can I designate an external user to manage other external user accounts?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I'm quite new to all things MS/AD and coming from the app developer side of things so please bear with me if i'm not using the right terminology. I can't find confirmation in the online docs for this, so grateful for any ideas or links that could be helpful.

The scenario: my organization is a O365 shop and have a bunch of stuff in Azure. One project is a custom platform with several web apps. Most are accessed by our own folks via SSO, but some of these apps will be accessed by external users from our partners/vendors. A couple of these are MS shops but most are not and we can't require MS accounts.

The twist: we need to delegate user management to our partners/vendors. So as an example, for app3 we will have tons of partner/vendor organizations that need access. We want to give 1 person from that organization the responsibility of inviting their colleagues and removing folks when anyone leaves their organization. In many cases, they won't necessarily have the same email address domains so we can't restrict/group in that manner. In other cases, we need each national office of a global organization to have its own delegated admin to manage staff so there may be separate organizations with users that have the same email address domain.

My questions: Is Azure AD B2C the right approach for this? 
Can it support this kind of delegated management (something like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-accessmanagement-self-service-group-management)?

Would we need configure a separate Azure AD B2C directories for each external organization or should these be groups within one Azure AD B2C directory?

Answer (score 3):

At this time **there is no out-of-the-box support for user management delegation in Azure AD B2C**, whether it's delegatin user management to other B2C admins using local (.onmicrosoft.com) accounts or external users using local (@myemail.com) or social accounts. Azure AD B2C does not support [self-service group management capabilities](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory/active-directory-accessmanagement-self-service-group-management) either. You can request either of these in the [Azure AD B2C feedback forum](http://aka.ms/aadb2cuv).

Is the same instance of these apps going to support people from these multiple organizations?

If the answer is no, meaning that your are going to have one instance of the app for organization A, and another for organization B, you can definitely have multiple Azure AD B2C directories and wire up each application to each directory.

If a single instance of these apps will need to support multiple of these organization, then I can think of two options for you:

1. **Use Azure AD B2C and build all the delegation and user management logic yourself**. You can have a [custom attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-custom-attr) to assign users their "organization" and another to indicate whether they can manage users or not. You would then need to create a user management UI that queries the Graph for all users that are in the same "organization" and let the user manage those. You would also need to build the invitation feature, first into this UI by creating the user through [Azure AD Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet) and setting its "organization" claim accordingly, and then by directing users to the Password Reset policy as their "account verification" flow.
2. **Use Azure AD and the B2B collaboration feature** (including its ability to [delegate invitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory/active-directory-b2b-delegate-invitations)). This also opens up the [self-service group management capabilities](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory/active-directory-accessmanagement-self-service-group-management) you referenced. If you don't want these users to get access to other things in your organization, you would probably want to create a separate Azure AD tenant for this and also invite people from your on Azure AD via B2B collaboration.

Conceptually, B2C is meant for external users, and Azure AD is meant for internal users, with B2B complementing those internal users with partners that collaborate enough with those internal users to be almost thought of as internal users. That being said, use whichever one best suits your needs. Don't forget to keep in mind that their pricing model is very different.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, @Saca! I was under the impression that B2B had built-in restrictions around external users' email address domains. Great to learn that this is not the case