# Does self service group ownership exist in Azure B2C?

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

We are POCing some identity solutions thats would allow customers conditional access to certain applications based on group membership.  I realize B2C doesn't natively support groups and I'd need to add a custom policy.

What about managing these groups?  I've made a test user a group owner, but of course they cannot see their groups in their access panel because it isn't natively supported.

Is there any solutions for self service group management for Azure B2C?

Side note - we were going to try to make this work with Azure B2B but we do not like that you cannot use Front Door to hide the microsoft domain during a login flow.  Unless I'm incorrect there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Currently, Azure AD B2C does not support self-service group management please check self-service group management capabilities***

- . Security groups created by self-service in the Access panel only owner can visible members but can't join in access panel this is also applicable in azure ad

To more in detail Please check this [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/enterprise-users/groups-self-service-management)  and [So thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44725261/in-azure-ad-b2c-can-i-designate-an-external-user-to-manage-other-external-user)  designed by [Saca](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3911457/saca) and team